# Me gustaría mostrar en mi NavigationDrawer las opciones en horizontal. (Como se ve en la imagen de abajo)

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, android-fragment, layout, android-drawerlayout

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría mostrar en mi NavigationDrawer las opciones en horizontal y que sea seleccionable como en la imagen que se ve, según lo que se seleccione modificaría el RecyclerView que tengo pensado implementar.

El proyecto lo tengo alojado [aquí](https://github.com/german-jongewaard/NavigationDrawer) en GitHub.

Muchas gracias!